# How to find sources of standard node.js functions

Tags: node.js

For example, if I'd like to read the source code of the [`process.chdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory) JavaScript function, how can I do that?

I can find `process.js` on [github](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/process.js) but not sure that's the right file. Is there an easier way to navigate from docs directly to source?

Comment: Are you using a particular IDE?  A lot of them have functionality to jump to function declarations.

Comment: That comes from the [native module](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node.cc#L1521-L1533)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a simple way to navigate directly from the web doc to source.  To find the code for a specific function, you have several choices:

1. Create a small test app that calls the function in question, run node-inspector and step into the function of interest.  That will take you right into the source code that your installed version of node.js is running.  You can then continue stepping or just examine the local source code shown in the debugger.
2. Grep your own node.js installation.  Since all the .js files are right there and in plain text, you can find it there.
3. Go to Github like you've done and find the relevant function.  This is not always easy to do (as you've discovered) and it doesn't guarantee that you're looking at the source for the exact same version you have installed.  If you're a Github wiz, you can always figure out how to see the right version, but that's a bit more work.

If the code you want is actually implemented in native code, then you're going to have to use options 3 or maybe option 2 (if you have native sources locally).

Comment: Very comprehensive. Thank you!